# ChartJs not showing top label

Tags: php, chart.js

My chartjs not showing label header, but i check all the code, i have nothing wrong, can some1 help me fix it? I already set the legend display : True

*Please ignore this the word not engough so i typing something to extend the word dsadasdnakdjakdakdkaldjlasjdladasdasdasdsadsadsadsadasdsa sAFAASD DCSDCAS CDECADA*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js'></script>
</head>

    <h1 class="header" align="center">Dashboard of Depression</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <body>
              <center>
                <h3>{{ title2 }}</h3>
              </center>
              <center>
                <canvas id="chart1" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
                <script>
                  // bar chart data
                  var barData = {
                    labels : [
                      {% for item in label2 %}
                       "{{ item }}",
                      {% endfor %}
                ],

                    datasets : [{
                      label: "Red",
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: "rgba(196, 93, 105, 0.3)",
                      strokeColor: "rgba(196, 93, 105, 0.3)",
                      pointColor: "rgba(196, 93, 105, 0.3)",
                      data : [
                        {% for item in value2 %}
                           "{{ item }}",
                          {% endfor %}
                    ]
                      },
                      {
                      label: "Blue",
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                      strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                      pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                      data : [
                        {% for item in value4 %}
                           "{{ item }}",
                          {% endfor %}
                    ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }

                 // get bar chart canvas
                 var mychart = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d");

                   steps = 10
                   max = {{max4}}

                 // draw bar chart
                 new Chart(mychart).Line(barData, {
                   scaleOverride: true,
                   scaleSteps: steps,
                   scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(max / steps),
                   scaleStartValue: 0,
                   scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
                   scaleShowGridLines : true,
                   barShowStroke : true,
                   scaleShowLabels: true,
                   xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
                   yAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
                   legend: {display: true}
                   }
                 );

                </script>
              </center>
            </body>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

[image: my graph]

[image: what i want]

Comment: I think `label: ["Blue"],` should be `label: "Blue",`

Comment: Is same result..

Comment: You're using really old version 1.0.2 of Chart.js, it will be hard to get advise for outdated software. Better move to current stable Chart.js version 2.9.3 first and adapt your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Solve: Reason of not showing ChartJS. The chart.js Is old version. Need to change it to the latest version